# Glossary Web Part for SharePoint 2007 / Glossary jQuery / Glossary Management System

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint-2007, versioning, glossary

Is there a Glossary Web part in SharePoint 2007 that can do the following:

[1] It allows user to enter keyword and its description.
Example:
Keyword: HTML 
Description: Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) is the predominant markup language for web pages.

[2] It allows keeping track of each new keyword and description - sort of like versioning.
Example:
If another person add on another keyword and its description, another version is formed.

[3] It auto-create links to keyword(s) that exist in descriptions if such keyword(s) exist.
Example:
Suppose there are 2 keywords as follows:
Keyword 1: SQL
Description: SQL is a programming language designed for managing data in relational database management systems (RDBMS)

Keyword 2: RDBMS
Description: A relational database management system (RDBMS) is a database management system (DBMS) that is based on the relational model

As seem in the above example, the web part should be able to detect the keyword 'RDBMS' in the keyword 'SQL' description and auto-create a link pointing to the Keyword 'RDBMS'. This will allow user to click on the 'RDBMS' inside the keyword 'SQL' description without searching it.

If the RDBMS keyword is removed, the web part will remove the link.

(If such web part does not exist in SharePoint 2007, other alternatives are welcome)

Thanks.

Wilson